# How do I change tabs and their data in React?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

This is the CSS of my JavaScript code and here where the error occurs. I tried to do so in HTML, CSS and simple JavaScript, it works for me but when I tried to do so in React it never happened. I just want to change the tab and its data/content:

```js
/******ABout Tabs ******/
const tabsContainer = document.querySelector('.about-tabs'),
aboutSection = document.querySelector('.about-section');
 

tabsContainer.addEventListener('click', (event) =>{

    if(event.target.classList.contains('tab-item') && !event.target.classList.contains('active')){

        tabsContainer.querySelector('.active').classList.remove('active');
        event.target.classList.add('active');

        const target = event.target.getAttribute('data-target');
        
        aboutSection.querySelector('.tab-content.active').classList.remove('active')
        aboutSection.querySelector(target).classList.add('active');

      
    }

});
It is the css of my code
```

```css
.about-section{
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.sec-padding{
  padding: 80px 0 0 0;
}
.section-title{
  padding: 0 15px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.section-title h2{
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: 40px;
}
.about-img{
  width: 40%;
  height:200px ;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.about-text{
  width: 50%;
  padding: 0 15px;

}
.about-img .img-box{
  background-color: var(--white-alpha-25);
  max-width: 380px;
  border: 1px solid var(--white-alpha-40);
  margin: auto;
}
.about-img .img-box img{
width: 100%;  
  padding-top: 50px;

}
.about-text h3{
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 20px 0;
}
.skill{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.skill .skill-item{
  margin: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid var(--white-alpha-40);
  background-color: var(--white-alpha-25);
  text-transform: capitalize;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  border-radius: 20px;

}
.about-tabs .tab-item{
  padding:2px 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  border:none;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  display:inline-block;
  color: var(--blue-dark);
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500px;
  margin: 0 30px 0 0;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.about-tabs .tab-item:last-child{
  margin: 0;
}
.about-tabs .tab-item::before{
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 0%;
   height: 1px;
   background-color: var(--blue-dark);
   transition: width 0.3s ease;
}
.about-tabs .tab-item:hover:before{
  width: 100%;
}
.about-tabs .tab-item.active::before{
   width: 100%;
   background-color: var(--main-color); 
}
.about-tabs .tab-item.active{
  color: var(--main-color);
  opacity:1;
  cursor:auto;
}
#edu{
  position: relative;
  
  
}
#exp{
  display: none;
}
#edu:first-child{
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.timeline::before{
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 1px;
  top :0;
  left: 5px;
  background-color: var(--main-color);
}
.about-text .tab-content{
  padding: 12px 0;
  display: none;

}
.about-text .tab-content.eduu{
  display:block;
  
}
.exper{
  display: none;
}


.tab-content  .timeline-item{
   margin-bottom: 30px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 0 0 40px;
}
.tab-content .timeline-item:last-child{
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.tab-content .timeline-item::before{
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 height: 11px;
 width: 11px;
 background-color: var(--main-color);
 left: 0;
 top:18px;
 border-radius: 50%;
}
.tab-content .timeline-item .date{
  display: block;
  color: var(--main-color);
  font-weight: 400;
  margin:  0 0 10px;
}
.about-text .timeline-item h4{
  font-size: 18;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}
.about-text .timeline-item h4 span{
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size:18px;
}
It is the react code[enter image description here][1]
```

```html
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import aboutimg from './image/about.png';
import Education from './Education';
import Experience from './Experience';




const About = () =>{
 

/******ABout Tabs ******/  

 my react componenet

    return(
        <>
        <section className='about-section sec-padding'>
            <div className='container' >
            <div className='roww' >
            <div className='section-title'>
            <h2>about me</h2>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div className='roww'>
             <div className='about-img'>
                 <div className='img-box'>
                     <img src={aboutimg} alt='About_pic'></img>
                 </div>
             </div>
             <div className='about-text'>
                 <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
                  Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
                   when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
                    specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into 
                    electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in 
                    the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, 
                    and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including
                     versions of Lorem Ipsum</p>
                     <h3>Skills</h3>
                     <div className='skill'>
                     <div className='skill-item'>html</div>
                     <div className='skill-item'>css</div>
                     <div className='skill-item'>javascript</div>
                     <div className='skill-item'>bootstrap</div>
                     <div className='skill-item'>python</div>
                     <div className='skill-item'>php</div>
                     <div className='skill-item'>wordpress</div>
                     <div className='skill-item'>c</div>
                     <div className='skill-item'>c++</div>
                     </div> 
                     
                <div className='about-tabs'>
                      <button  type='button' 
                      className='tab-item active' data-tab='#education'>education</button>
                      <button  type='button' 
                       className='tab-item'  data-tab='#experience'>experience</button>
                </div> 
                <div>
               <Education  className='timeline-item active' />
               <br/>
               <div className='exper'>
               <Experience className='timeline-item'  />
               </div>
                </div> 
                 
             </div>
            </div>

            </div>
        </section>

        </>
    );
};

export default About;
```

Comment: Please try to explain better your issue and create a StackBlitz with the code

Comment: i have created to compnents to show data under two tabs

Comment: but i cant able to change data when i click on another tab

Answer (score 0):

You can add onClick event-handler on element and put above code inside the function. It will automatically invoked and things works fine.
Read this one:
https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html